# Select statement in login. Query failed

Tags: php, select, authentication

This is my code for check login. It return query failed. I don't know which syntax is wrong. Any help ?
Do I need to SELECT everything in my table only ? In my login page, there are only need username, password and role. But in my table there are other things to as stated at my $_SESSION below. Do I need to call back everything in my table or something ? Because my coding can't read the query. There is no syntax error but when I try to login, query failed appear.

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'database.php';

//to store validation errors
$errmsg_arr = array();

//validation error flag
$errflag = false;

//function to sanitize values from the form. Preventing the SQL injection
function clean ($str){
    $str = @trim($str);
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
        $str = striplashes ($str);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}

//sanitize POST values
$myusername = clean ($_POST['username']);
$mypassword = clean ($_POST['password']);
$role = clean ($_POST['role']);

//input validations
if ($myusername = ''){
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Insert your username';
    $errflag = true;
}
if ($mypassword = ''){
    $errmsg_arr[]= 'Insert you password';
    $errflag = true;
}

//if there are input validation, redirect back to home
if ($errflag){
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
    session_write_close();
    header("location:index.php");
    exit();
}

$qry = "SELECT user_id, username, name, password, role FROM student WHERE username = '$myusername', password = '".md5($_POST['password'])."' AND role = '$role' ";
$result = mysql_query($qry);

if ($result){
    if (mysql_num_rows($result)== 1){

        session_regenerate_id();
        $student = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);  
        $_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID']= $student['user_id'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_NAME']= $student['name'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_GENDER']= $student['gender'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_MATRIC']= $student['matric'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_COLLEGE']= $student['college'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_FACULTY']= $student['faculty'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_COURSE']= $student['course'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_EMAIL']= $student['email'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_PHONE']= $student['phone'];     
        session_write_close();
        header("location: profile.php");
        exit();
    }else {
        header ("location: login_failed.php");
        exit();
    }
}else {
    die ("Query failed");
}
?>
```

Comment: **[Don't use mysql_*; use mysqli_* or PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?rq=1).**

Comment: You're checking the return values of your database calls; but if they've failed, you can use `mysql_error()` to get the actual error message from the database.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `and` instead of `,` between username and password

```
WHERE username = '$myusername' and  password = '".md5($_POST['password'])."' AND role = '$role'
```

instead of

```
WHERE username = '$myusername', password = '".md5($_POST['password'])."' AND role = '$role'
```

PHP

```
 $result = mysql_query($qry) or die (mysql_error());
 if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){

    session_regenerate_id();
    $student = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);  
    $_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID']= $student['user_id'];
    $_SESSION['SESS_NAME']= $student['name'];
    $_SESSION['SESS_GENDER']= $student['gender'];
    $_SESSION['SESS_MATRIC']= $student['matric'];
    $_SESSION['SESS_COLLEGE']= $student['college'];
    $_SESSION['SESS_FACULTY']= $student['faculty'];
    $_SESSION['SESS_COURSE']= $student['course'];
    $_SESSION['SESS_EMAIL']= $student['email'];
    $_SESSION['SESS_PHONE']= $student['phone'];     
    session_write_close();
    header("location: profile.php");
    exit();
}else {
    header ("location: login_failed.php");
    exit();
}
```

**NOTE**: Use mysqli_* functions or PDO instead of mysql_* functions(deprecated)

Comment: for the query, the problem solved. THANK YOU ! But now, there is error  keep on saying the login failed even the username and password is correct.

Comment: Remove `
if ($result){
    if (mysql_num_rows($result)== 1){` and use like `
    if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0){`

Answer (score 1):

In your `WHERE` clause you have `username='$myusername', password=` which should be `username='$myusername' AND password=`

If you had a checked for the query failing, you'd probably could have found out that yourself, e.g.

```
$result = mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());
```

---

Also keep in mind that `mysql_*` functions are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation) and hence should not be used in new code. You can use PDO or MySQLi instead. See [this thread on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?rq=1) for more information.

In addition to that, `md5` is not a secure method to hash passwords!

Answer (score 0):

try out this code

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'database.php';

//to store validation errors
$errmsg_arr = array();

//validation error flag
$errflag = false;

//function to sanitize values from the form. Preventing the SQL injection
function clean ($str){
    $str = @trim($str);
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
        $str = striplashes ($str);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}

//sanitize POST values
$myusername = clean ($_POST['username']);
$mypassword = clean ($_POST['password']);
$role = clean ($_POST['role']);

//input validations
if ($myusername = ''){
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Insert your username';
    $errflag = true;
}
if ($mypassword = ''){
    $errmsg_arr[]= 'Insert you password';
    $errflag = true;
}

//if there are input validation, redirect back to home
if ($errflag){
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
    session_write_close();
    header("location:index.php");
    exit();
}

try{
    $qry = "SELECT user_id, username, name, password, role FROM student WHERE username = '$myusername' AND password = '".md5($_POST['password'])."' AND role = '$role' ";
$result = mysql_query($qry);

    if (mysql_num_rows($result)== 1){

        session_regenerate_id();
        $student = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);  
        $_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID']= $student['user_id'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_NAME']= $student['name'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_GENDER']= $student['gender'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_MATRIC']= $student['matric'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_COLLEGE']= $student['college'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_FACULTY']= $student['faculty'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_COURSE']= $student['course'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_EMAIL']= $student['email'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_PHONE']= $student['phone'];     
        session_write_close();
        header("location: profile.php");
        exit();
    }else {
        header ("location: login_failed.php");
        exit();
    }

}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation of what changes you've made?

Comment: yes , first , i modified the query in the where section , i added "and " between username and password , and second , i added try / catch , if there is any error regarding the DB resource value , the catch will print the error

Comment: problem solved thank you ! but now i can't login even I've entered username, password and role correctly (according to my database). Help ?

Comment: I don't believe mysql_* functions create exceptions, though, so you need to handle errors differently.

Comment: please login using a correct username and pass and role , and try to var_dump(mysql_num_rows($result)) to check if the code is getting inside the if statment